# Show default image until Image downloads wp8

Tags: image, windows-phone-8

I am working on a travel application for windows phone 8 devices. Search result returns many records with many image urls. I want to show the default image of my application until the actual image is downloaded and set in  control.

I am using a very simple code below.

```
 <Image  Margin="3"
Grid.Column="0"  
Source="{Binding Thumbnail}"
HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
Height="130" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="130"/>
```

The `Thumbnail` field returns the string url for the image to show.

The image finally will be shown as below. I want to show my default image until it downloads.

When image is not fully available app should show like below.

[image]

and when it fully downloaded it should show like below.

[image]

Comment: Can you post your class which you are binding

Comment: Simple solution would be two use two images, and show the second only when it was finished downloading. You could have a boolean property on a view model like `IsThumbnailReady` to control visibility.

Answer (score 2):

Best solution I've found ( and that I'm using in my apps ) is just to use the Coding4Fun controls lib! It has a control called `SuperImage` that has an extra property called `PlaceHolder` where you set the default image and when your actual image is downloaded - this is being set through the Source property - it will fade out and fade in this actual image!

Take a look here for more details http://metronuggets.com/2013/06/11/coding4fun-toolkit-introducing-superimage/

Answer (score 0):

Try to add dynamically.

```
 Uri uri = new Uri("image.png", UriKind.Relative);
 ImageSource imgSource = new BitmapImage(uri);
 img_result.Source = imgSource;
```

set `imgSource` to your class which you bind.

Comment: no you didn't got my point, it would do the same. in binding i am assigning the image source as string, and you are just saying to bind it with bitmap. What will be shown before the image is assigned? currently it is showing empty and in your case it will also show empty until it downloads image, i want to show some image until it downloads? like it does in foursquare. please read Edit

Comment: Add image which you want to display until download. add you image path to `image.png`

Answer (score 0):

```
     <Image x:Name ="img" Margin="3" Grid.Column="0"  Source="{Binding Thumbnail}"HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="130" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="130"/>
```

You may be having a function in View Model to update the Image when it loads so in starting in xaml you can give img.Source ="/Assets/Images/dragon.png" whatever your default image and when you call the function and it returns the value you can change it to the image.

Answer (score 0):

Simply, use two `Image` controls in a `Grid` layout, one with the local placeholder source and one with the remote `Binding`. As soon as the remote image gets rendered, it covers the local placeholder image.

```cs
<Grid Grid.Column="0">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Image">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top"/>
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="130"/>
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="130"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="3"/>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Image Source="Assets/Placeholder.png"/>
    <Image Source="{Binding Thumbnail}"/>
</Grid>
```

For a better effect, I generally subscribe to the `ImageOpened` event of the remote image that triggers a `StoryBoard` animation for changing the opacity of the remote image from 0 to 1 (just a suggestion).